# HTML code that changes with user's input in Shiny

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Here's the basics of my problem:

1. In simplified terms, suppose that the user in `ui.R` gets to insert the name of an artist using a regular text input. This is then saved in `input$artist_name`.
2. Switching to `server.R`, some stats about the artist's top track are then displayed using some intermediate calls and computations. I then use `renderPlot()`to put a plot in `output$Plot`.
3. **Here is where I run into trouble.** I would like to include a player (using just basic HTML, this is not the problem) which allows the user to play the track. However, it seems to me as if I need to use the information I got in `server.R` (since here is where I learn what the most popular track is and, subsequently, its URL) to "push" the URL of the track back to `ui.R` so that I can include the player in a panel using the `HTML()` function. Is this possible? To me, it kind of seems as if what I want to do is similar to what you can do with `uiOutput()` and `renderUI()`, although obviously not for making a custom UI depending on the user's input but rather some custom HTML code depending on the input.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `renderUI` to send arbitrary HTML as long as the output is wrapped in `HTML()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but it is not too hard to create arbitrary HTML in the server and send it to UI. Here is an example:

```
library(shiny)

ui =fluidPage(
    textInput("test","Write here"),
    uiOutput("example")
  )

server=shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


    output$example <- renderUI({
      HTML(paste0("<div style='color:red;'>",input$test,"</div>"))
    })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```